# Should I keep app state in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I try to make some app with stopwatch feature and having some confusing points.
First, what is the proper way to keep state of the stopwatch (start, pause, stop). Should I keep this state in core data ?

Second, I created core data entity with Date property to keep start time. Should I delete this entity each time the stopwatch is reset or keep it in separate record ?

Answer (score 3):

CoreData is very heavy handed for what you want unless you want to keep lots of different records in very specific ways

NSUserDefaults would do fine, they are persistent unless you delete the app

This [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/) is very good. So say if you had your two variables time_started and time_ended, you'd get the time between then and write them into the UserDefaults. If you want to keep a record of multiple entries use a loop that increments a count or index.

Dont have time at the mo to write any code but do that tutorial and you might find that NSUserDefaults is better.

Hope it helps

Comment: And in the future if I keep histories for each records user made, and used core data how should I keep state ?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is the easier I find and much more manageable in future projects but since you're so eager to use core data I was nice and found pretty much exactly what you needed :)
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/

This is a lap timer stored in CoreData, timer starts in viewDidLoad I think and every time the button is pressed the timer stops and the table is updated with a time
Ways to change it: 
Have another view before that takes a name imput
Make a button to start the timer
Have a label to display the current lap time (just drag the tableView lower for room)

Comment: Your link answer my second question on how to keep the data, but I still don't sure on how to keep state of my stopwatch (start, pause, and stop) in the link you provided is save each lap and don't keep state whether timer pause or not. Should I have isPause and isEnd BOOL type ? for that state.